Is it allowed to put a single letter on the board?
If there is already the word "APPLE" on the board and I have an "S", is it allowed to make it "APPLES" or do I always have to put at least two letters on the board?

You mean like this... https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/39126/11571

Yes, that is a legal play as you are forming a new word.

Yes, you can play just a single tile. The official rules state so explicitly:


The first turn


The first word must be at least 2 letters long.
...


Every other turn


...
A single letter may be played on subsequent turns.


And the tip

Add a letter (or letters) to an existing word. And
build off it, if you can!

Further solidifies that your play can be just extending a word (you are encouraged to also build off of it "if you can").

Thank you. So Weather Vane's answer is not fully correct, as you must start with a 2-letter word. Also I knew that you can play a single letter, I just wasn't sure if you have to create a new word (e..g, adding a vertical letter to a horizontal word) or if you can really simply extend an existing word without also building a new one.

@D.R. Ah, yes. I'll add the bit from the tips section to further that point.

Not only is this legitimate, it is often an extremely good move. Not "APPLE" -> "APPLES" - that will get you at most 30 points (A 1, P 3, P 3, L 1, E 1, S 1 = 10, with S on Triple Word = 30, and a good player would be unlikely to play a word like APPLE to end just before an available Triple Word space). But if you can place Q or Z on a Triple Letter next to two good vowels you get 62 points. If one of the new words is more than just two letters then you can get even more points.
